# Importing .kmz file into PostgreSQL

Tags: python, postgresql, kml, ogr2ogr, kmz

I have several (100+) .kmz files that I would like to import into my PostgreSQL database. I have this ogr2ogr command that works fine getting it into the database, but creates a new table every time:

```
C:\Radio Stations>ogr2ogr -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"host=localhost user=postgres dbname=postgres password=password port=5433" "file.kmz"
```

What do I put in that cmd to put all of the .kmz files into the same table?

I'm using PostGIS 2.2.1, PostgreSQL 9.5.1, Python 3.6.1

Comment: use -update to load to one table using many file as the source. http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html

Comment: C:\Radio Stations>ogr2ogr -update -append -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"host=localhost user=postgres dbname=postgres password=passw port=5433" "file.kmz"       still adds another table, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: you are probably not setting the table try using '-nln mytable'

Comment: Can you please answer your own question for future visitors? Thanks! @Matt

Comment: @Mapperz if you would like to answer this question, I'll give you credit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Table name needs to be set in the command to load many kmz into one table.

```
C:\Radio Stations>ogr2ogr -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"host=localhost user=postgres dbname=postgres password=password port=5433" "file.kmz" -nln mytable
```

**-nln mytable** command will specify a table name to load into.